# Get recipient email address within the notification specific for each recipient

Tags: solspace-freeform

**Update, summarised the question**

**I am trying to send multiple notification emails, each with unique content, to a list of user-defined recipients using a single FreeForm form.**

I have a Freeform enquiry form on a property web site. The form is to allow visitors to enquire about multiple properties from a single form. They fill in their details and the enquirer's details are sent to each property owner.

The properties are entries with the owner as the entry author.

I am looping through the selected property entries and add each recipient to the form using recipient_email_user[]. This bit is working fine.

At the moment I have a single textarea which contains the names of all the properties that are being enquired about. This means that each owner receives an email that contains the names of their property AND the other owners.

I really need to  have each notification show the details for the property belonging only to that particular owner.

Is there a way I can get the recipients email address within each notification or can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: Is Postmaster an option?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster

Comment: Yeah! Postmaster, that's a great suggestion!!!

Comment: I'm looking at using Postmaster. Just trying to figure out how to do it as I will need a custom hook/plugin.